# Replace logic board on MacBook pro retina early 2013

Tags: macbook-pro

i have to replace my broken logic board on my MacBook Pro retina display early 2013. I am wondering what alternatives I have: since I have to replace it, can I also speed it up with something from the late 2013 or 2014 series? Where can I order replacements? I tried fixit.com, but they only have a used 8GB board.

Comment: Why do you have to replace the logic board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inquire at [Other World Computing].[1](https://www.macsales.com) They will know which part and why.

The classic resource for complete info on every Apple machine is everymac.com.

Comment: thanks for the info, but it looks like OWC does not have logic board replacements...